# Firefox changed its fonts on all sites without me doing anything and I am unable to change it back

Tags: debian, kde, firefox, fonts, fontconfig

Without me doing anything, firefox changed the fonts (the degree of change is differenet for different sites) to something else (please see image) and I am unable to change it back.

This is a clean profile that has no addons.

[image: messed up firefox fonts]

I have ensured that the settings are at its default

[image: settings are at default]

And this problem does not affect TorBrowser which is based on firefox and Chromium.

[image: torbrowser no font problem]

I am on Debian 10 (Buster, testing), firefox 59, KDE.

Solutions I tried:

- I have checked the KDE settings for font.
- I have almost all possible fonts installed (6GB).
- Deleted everything in the .cache folder and ran fc-cache -rv.
- Installed a fresh firefox-esr (v52) with new profile and no addons, and it has the same problem.

Why is this happening, and how do I solve it.

Thank you so much for reading this.

Comment: disable uBlock, try again, verify, change settings accordingly

Comment: @A.B, thank you. I have tried with no addons at all. It did not help. Is there something else that I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Renamed the /home/user/.fonts folder to .fonts-disabled.
Ran fc-cache -rv
Now those fonts will not be used by the system.

Problem solved - firefox now has correct fonts.

That folder had fonts that I have been collecting for 15yrs (6gb), and something there was corrupting firefox. And after getting rid of it, I realized that I don't need many fonts (just the basic ones from debian plus mscorefonts was more than enough). Even other language fonts (like japanese) are still working.